# ¿Forma de acceso a "this" en anidamiento?

Tags: javascript, typescript, funciones, clase, this

Estoy tratando de acceder a un "this". Lo he intentado con una función flecha y sin ella pero no veo la forma.
¿Alguna idea?

```
class Personaje{
  num:number = 10;
  
  static caracter = {
     fuerza(){
       this.num = 200;  // error!
     },

     fuerzaPrueba:(() => {
       this.num = 500;  // error!
     }
  };

}
```

Quizás para una mayor aclaración decir que mi deseo es poder acceder desde fuera de la clase de la siguiente forma y con los elementos existentes:

```
personaje.caracter.fuerza()
```

Muy agradecido a todos por las aclaraciones.
Al final he sustituido static por public y aplicando la idea de una instancia.

```
class personaje{
  num:number = 10;
  
  public caracter = {
     fuerza(instancia){
       instancia.num = 200;
     },
  };
}
```

```
pepe.caracter.fuerza(pepe) // Hay forma de evitar pasarle el parámetro, puesto que siempre será el nombre del objeto?
```

Comment: Se me ocurre que inyectes la instancia (`this`) al método dentro de tu objeto anidado, claro, no se llamaría `this`. Por ejemplo: `fuerza(instancia) { instancia.num = 200 }`. La variable `this` dentro del objeto anidado (`caracter`) hace referencia al objeto y no a la Clase que lo contiene (`Personaje`). Por otro lado, es usual nombrar las Clases con la primera letra mayúscula. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

En javascript cada instancia tiene su propio `this`.

No tienes acceso al `this` porque estas creando otro objeto nuevo que tendrá su propio `this`,(las llaves `{}` crean otra instancia de objeto).

```javascript
// este objeto tendrá su propio this, que será distinto al de Personaje
static caracter = {
    // podrias definir la variable num y te funcionaría,
// pero en mi opinión no es correcto hacer esto, estas duplicando otra vez la clase Personaje
     num: 10,
     fuerza() {
       this.num = 200;  // error!
     },

     fuerzaPrueba: () => {
       this.num = 500;  // error!
     }
  };
```

Si quieres que la clase `Personaje` cree un nuevo caracter, puedes crear un método para eso que te devuelva otra instancia de la clase `Personaje`.

Si quieres crear diferentes tipos de caracteres, te recomiendo leer sobre el patrón *factory*.

```javascript
class Personaje {
  num: number = 10;
  
  constructor(num: number) {
    this.num = num;
  }
  
  setFuerza(fuerza: number) {
    this.num = fuerza;
  }

  static crearCaracter(fuerza: number) {
    return new Personaje(fuerza);
  };

}

const caracter1 = Personaje.crearCaracter(100);
// si le quieres cambiar la fuerza, llamas al metodo setFuerza
caracter1.setFuerza(500);

const caracter2 = Personaje.crearCaracter(10);
```

Comment: Muy bien explicado, pero ¿de qué forma esto responde la pregunta original? Si se tiene un objeto como atributo estático de una Clase y se desea trabajar con los atributos públicos de la Clase que contiene dicho objeto, ¿cómo lo logra? Creo que esa es la pregunta en cuestión. Aunque tu enfoque, claramente válido, da una respuesta alternativa, no veo cómo responde la pregunta original. Saludos

Comment: En mi opinión, las propiedades estáticas son como singletons, que no se deberían modificar.  Si quiere cambiar/crear las propiedades de un objeto, ese comportamiento debería ser "responsabilidad" del objeto que las tiene, o exponer métodos para manipular dicho comportamiento. Lo que le has comentado es una manera de resolverlo. La verdad es que tampoco sabemos muy bien lo que espera el usuario, solo ha expuesto parte del problema

Answer (score 2):

El error que te lanza es:

```
'this' cannot be referenced in a static property initializer.(2334)
```

Esto en resumen significa que no puedes utilizar la palabra clave `this` dentro de un objeto statico. Si quitas el modificador `static` te funcionara:

```
class personaje{
  num:number = 10;
  
  caracter = {
      num: this.num,
     fuerza(){
       this.num = 200;  // error!
     },

     fuerzaPrueba:() => {
       this.num = 500;  // error!
     }
  };

}
```

Comment: Creo que eso no es lo que pretende el OP. Su pregunta no es del todo clara tampoco. Sin embargo, sugerir quitar la palabra `static` cambia la funcionalidad del atributo, cosa que  tal vez no sea lo que se requiere. Te sugiero que revises tu respuesta y argumentes claramente cómo se podría usar el atributo `caracter`. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Ya te han dado dos respuesta, en ambas te dan sugerencias para mejorar o modificar tu implementación. Sin embargo, usaré mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/469465/forma-de-acceso-a-this-en-anidamiento#comment836191_469465) y lo argumentaré en esta respuesta.

Tu pregunta original: *¿Forma de acceso a “this” en anidamiento?*, tiene como respuesta: no puedes acceder directamente a la variable `this` del ámbito de la Clase (`Personaje`) desde el atributo estático de tipo Objeto llamado `caracter`, ya que este objeto tiene su propio ámbito y toda función declarada dentro de este objeto estará supeditada a dicho ámbito.

Dicho de otra forma: el objeto `this` dentro de `caracter` es diferente del objeto `this` dentro de `Personaje`.

Mi propuesta es simple, inyectar la instancia (porque `num` es una propiedad de la instancia y no de la Clase, al no ser declarada como `static`) pasándola como argumento a tu función dentro del Objeto `caracter`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
class Personaje implements IPersonaje {
  num = 10;  // no necesitas declarar el tipo cuando hace una asignación. (Typescript)
  static caracter = {
    fuerza(instancia: IPersonaje) {
      instancia.num = 50;
    }
  }
}
```

Como puedes observar, el método `fuerza()` del Objeto estático `caracter` en tu clase Personaje, recibe un argumento llamado `instancia`, el cual implementa la interfaz `IPersonaje` (es lo usual en Typescript, ya que así tengo la certeza que `instancia` tiene un atributo llamado `num`). La Clase personaje también implementa dicha interfaz.

Así, podrías usar tu método `fuerza` de la siguiente forma:

```js
class Personaje {
  num = 10;
  static caracter = {
    fuerza(instancia) {
      instancia.num = 50;
    }
  }
}
// creamos una instancia de la clase
const personaje = new Personaje();

console.log(personaje.num); // 10

// usamos el método fuerza del Objeto estático
// los atributos estáticos sólo pueden ser invocados
// directamente desde la clase y no desde la instancia
Personaje.caracter.fuerza(personaje);

console.log(personaje.num); // 50

// nuestra instancia no tiene un atributo caracter
console.log(personaje.caracter); // undefined

// nuestra Clase no tiene un atributo num
console.log(Personaje.num); // undefined
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

De esta forma, estarías *inyectando* tu instancia al método estático y podrías trabajar con los atributos de dicha instancia. Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Mejor usar un setter, en vez de crear una propiedad estática a la que tienes que pasarle una instancia no?

Comment: @hawks, la respuesta es más a modo ilustrativo, sin alterar *mucho* la estructura de la Clase y sus atributos. Además, recuerda que en general, los *getters* y *setters* se consideran un anti patrón en OOP. Saludos